# FileUploader.js throws TypeError: postData.data.set is not a function in Safari

Tags: javascript, error, file-upload, magento-2.1.8, uielement

In my custom form I use the file uploader element:

```
<field name="image">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Image</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
            <item name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="string">jpg jpeg gif png svg</item>
            <item name="maxFileSize" xsi:type="number">20000000</item>
            <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="path/to/imageUpload"/>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

It works fine in the Chrome & FireFox, **but in the Safari it throws an error**:

> TypeError: postData.data.set is not a function. (In ‘postData.data.set(‘param_name’, this.paramName)‘, ‘postData.data.set’ is undefined)
>
> file-uploader.js:307

Investigating the code I have found that all is ok in the **Magento 2.1.8** (in my opinion):

```
    /**
     * Handler which is invoked prior to the start of a file upload.
     *
     * @param {Event} e - Event obejct.
     * @param {Object} data - File data that will be uploaded.
     */
    onBeforeFileUpload: function (e, data) {
        var file     = data.files[0],
            allowed  = this.isFileAllowed(file),
            target   = $(e.target);

        if (allowed.passed) {
            target.on('fileuploadsend', function (event, postData) {
/** Line 307 */ postData.data.set('param_name', this.paramName);
                $(event.currentTarget).off('fileuploadsend');
            }.bind(data));

            target.fileupload('process', data).done(function () {
                data.submit();
            });
        } else {
            this.notifyError(allowed.message);
        }
    },
```

But code in the **Magento 2.1.7** looks different, and it does not use the `FormData.set` method directly:

```
    /**
     * Handler which is invoked prior to the start of a file upload.
     *
     * @param {Event} e - Event obejct.
     * @param {Object} data - File data that will be uploaded.
     */
    onBeforeFileUpload: function (e, data) {
        var file     = data.files[0],
            allowed  = this.isFileAllowed(file);

        if (allowed.passed) {
            $(e.target).fileupload('process', data).done(function () {
                data.submit();
            });
        } else {
            this.notifyError(allowed.message);
        }
    },
```

Then I have found a similar bug report on the github:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10520

Unfortunately it has been closed by magento team without an any information.

Future investigation leaded me to the *developer.mozilla.org* page where I have found interesting information: they say that **Safari does not supports the `FormData.set` method at all**:

[image: developer.mozilla.org FormData.set method description]

**So question is:** how in this case it can be used in the **core magento**? Is any known workaround for this error or I missed something?

**PS:** Tested in the *Content > Design > Configuration > Header > Upload Logo* and the standard file uploader does not works too - throwing the same error.

**PPS:** Safari Version 10.1.2 (12603.3.8)

**PPPS:** I have found the [similar question on the StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38897791/formdata-get-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-safari) (not in Magento context), but it has been asked more than year ago...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a magento bug after version 2.1.8 and **it is fixed in the Magento 2.2.0**. Here is updated code:

```
    /**
     * Handler which is invoked prior to the start of a file upload.
     *
     * @param {Event} e - Event object.
     * @param {Object} data - File data that will be uploaded.
     */
    onBeforeFileUpload: function (e, data) {
        var file     = data.files[0],
            allowed  = this.isFileAllowed(file),
            target   = $(e.target);

        if (allowed.passed) {
            target.on('fileuploadsend', function (event, postData) {
                postData.data.append('param_name', this.paramName);
            }.bind(data));

            target.fileupload('process', data).done(function () {
                data.submit();
            });
        } else {
            this.notifyError(allowed.message);
        }
    },
```

as you can see now Magento use the method `postData.data.append` which doe not throws errors in the Safari.