# Magento 2 : admin file field max upload size

Tags: magento2, admin, file-upload

I'm trying to restrict the weight of the uploaded file in admin, I found the 'maxFileSize' in Magento documentation but it's not working :

```
$fieldset->addField(
  'files',
  'file',
  [
    'name' => 'file',
    'label' => __('File'),
    'title' => __('File'),
    'maxFileSize' => 2097152,
    'required' => false,
    'note' => 'File size must be less than 2 Mb.'
  ]
);
```

Thanks !

Comment: you can restrict it from controller save action.

Comment: Check out this link where maxfilesize is being used in the form field: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193784/fileuploader-js-throws-typeerror-postdata-data-set-is-not-a-function-in-safari

Answer (score 0):

I think I would use php.ini instead.

To ensure that file uploads work correctly, the post_max_size directive should be a little larger than the upload_max_filesize. For example, the following settings demonstrate how to set a file upload limit to 20 megabytes:

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 21M
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but by doing this I will limit all files fields and I just want to custom the max size for this specific field.

Comment: Ahhhh, well that's a horse of a different color for sure!